# Using Nonce for my Form

Tags: php, plugin-development, forms, nonce

Essentially I need to verify my data using a nonce, but I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. What I'm trying to do is remove a menu option for a user that isn't an admin. If a checkbox is checked and the form is submitted, that menu item will be removed for anyone that cannot manage options.

EDIT: Got my code posted here instead of Gist:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Developer Mode Tools 02
Author: Tyler Gerig
Version: 1.1
Description: Add developer mode options to your wordpress installation.
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
*/

function pretty_dump($dump){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($dump);
        echo '</pre>';
}

/**
*Add an options page for the plugin.
*
*@since 1.0.
*
*@return void
*/
function check_admin_page(){
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        //pretty_dump($screen->base);
        if($screen->base == 'settings_page_tgdmt_options_page'){
                if($_POST){
                                $menus_to_remove = array();
                                $tgdmt_menus = $_POST;
                                foreach($tgdmt_menus as $tgdmt_menu){
                                        if($tgdmt_menu != 'Save Changes'){
                                                $menus_to_remove[] = $tgdmt_menu;
                                        }
                                }
                                update_option( 'tgdmt_menu_settings', array_map('sanitize_text_field', $menus_to_remove) );
                                //pretty_dump($menus_to_remove);
                }

        }
        if(isset( $_POST[ 'tdgmt_plugin_noncename']) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[' tdgmt_plugin_noncename'], plugins_url( __FILE__))){
                echo 'Nonce verified';
        }else{
                echo 'Nonce not verified';
        }

}
add_action('admin_head', 'check_admin_page');

function tgdmt_remove_menus(){
        if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
                if(get_option('tgdmt_menu_settings')){
                        $tgdmt_remove = get_option('tgdmt_menu_settings');
                        foreach($tgdmt_remove as $remove){
                                remove_menu_page($remove);
                        }
                }
        }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'tgdmt_remove_menus', 11);

function tgdmt_add_options_page(){
        //Add new page under the "Settings tab"
        add_options_page(
                __( 'Developer Mode Tools Options' ),
                __( 'Developer Mode Tools Options' ),
                'manage_options',
                'tgdmt_options_page',
                'tgdmt_render_options_page'
        );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'tgdmt_add_options_page' );


function tgdmt_menu_settings() {
    // Register a binary value called ""
    register_setting(
        'tgdmt_menu_settings',
        'tgdmt_menu_settings',
        ''
    );
}
add_action('admin_init','tgdmt_menu_settings');


function tgdmt_render_options_page(){
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
                <h2><?php _e( 'Developer Mode Tools Options'); ?></h2>
                <form action="<?php //plugins_url( 'tgdmt_update_menu.php' , dirname(__FILE__) )?>" method="post">
                        <p>
                        <?php wp_nonce_field(plugins_url(__FILE__), 'tgdmt_plugin_noncename'); ?>
                        <?php
                        global $menu;
                                //pretty_dump($menu);
                                $i = 0; 
                                //if( current_user_can('manage_options')){
                                        foreach($menu as $item){

                                                if($item[0] != ''){
                                                        $menu_name = trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'',$item[0]));
                                                        echo '<input name="menu'.$i.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$item[2].'" ' . checked( 1, '', false ) . ' />'. $menu_name . '<br>';
                                                        $i++;
                                                        //echo '<input id="tgdmt_disable'.$i.'" name="tgdmt_disable'.$i.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$item[2].'" ' . checked( 1, $status, false ) . ' />'.__($menu_name, 'tgdmt').'<br>';
                                                }
                                        }
                                ?>

                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', 'tgdmt' ); ?>">
                        </p>
                </form>
        </div>
        <?php



}
```

Comment: What does "save my data into a nonce" mean? Are you sure you know what an nonce is?

Comment: Also, posting "here in a block of code" is pretty much the rule, so post your code here. Look for the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: I don't, that's my point. I don't really understand nonces, but I need to use one. I probably worded it wrong, but I do need to use a nonce and verify that nonce for my form.

Comment: Post your answer in the "Answer" box, please.

Comment: I would, but I can't for another 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do. I needed

```
if(isset( $_POST[ 'tdgmt_plugin_noncename']) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tdgmt_plugin_noncename'], plugins_url( __FILE__))){
```

to be above

```
 if($screen->base == 'settings_page_tgdmt_options_page'){
```

as well as fixing my typos of

```
tdgmt_plugin_noncename
```

instead of

```
tgdmt_plugin_noncename
```